# Logging Modbus Data to XML

Tags: c#, xml, logging, modbus

currently I am facing some difficulties in developing the code to log modbus data into XML format instead of CSV in c#. Following is the code which I have done:

```
    public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeRegisters();
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Start Modbus RTU Service
            ModbusRTUProtocol.Start();
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            //HMI Display (Label) Controls
            displayControl1.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0];
            displayControl2.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[1];
            displayControl3.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[2];

            //HMI Editor Controls
            editorControl1.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[3];
            editorControl2.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[4];
            editorControl3.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[5];
            editorControl4.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[6];
            editorControl5.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[7];
            editorControl6.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[8];
            editorControl7.Register = ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[9];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ModbusRTUProtocol.Stop();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeRegisters()
    {
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Clear();
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 0 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 1 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 2 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 3 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 4 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 5 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 6 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 7 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 8 });
        ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = 9 });
    }

    private void bttnSetEC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bttnSetEC.Text == "Set EC")
        {
            bttnSetEC.Text = "Lock Setting";
            editorControl1.Enabled = true;
            editorControl2.Enabled = true;
            editorControl3.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (bttnSetEC.Text == "Lock Setting")
        {
            bttnSetEC.Text = "Set EC";
            editorControl1.Enabled = false;
            editorControl2.Enabled = false;
            editorControl3.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void bttnSetpH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bttnSetpH.Text == "Set pH")
        {
            bttnSetpH.Text = "Lock Setting";
            editorControl4.Enabled = true;
            editorControl5.Enabled = true;
            editorControl6.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (bttnSetpH.Text == "Lock Setting")
        {
            bttnSetpH.Text = "Set pH";
            editorControl4.Enabled = false;
            editorControl5.Enabled = false;
            editorControl6.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void bttnPumpAutoOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bttnPumpAutoOn.Text == "Set Pump Automation")
        {
            bttnPumpAutoOn.Text = "Lock Pump Setting";
            editorControl7.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (bttnPumpAutoOn.Text == "Lock Pump Setting")
        {
            bttnPumpAutoOn.Text = "Set Pump Automation";
            editorControl7.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void WriteLogInformation(string filename, string info1, string info2)
    {
        StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sbuilder))
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                w.WriteStartElement("LogInfo");
                w.WriteElementString("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                w.WriteElementString("Info1", info1);
                w.WriteElementString("Info2", info2);
                w.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(filename, true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            w.WriteLine(sbuilder.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = @"c:\modbustest.xmllog";
        //private static FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\mcb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0]);

            //WriteLogInformation(filename, string.Format(ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0]), string.Format("pH {0}", ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[1]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

This is the part which I stuck on:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = @"c:\modbustest.xmllog";
        //private static FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\mcb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0]);

            //WriteLogInformation(filename, string.Format(ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0]), string.Format("pH {0}", ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[1]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to read the coil and output the data read into xml logging file. However this is where I stuck on, can't get the it output the data into XML.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Xml Serialize on works with class objects.  You can use a Net library like Xml Linq to go directly from the Registers to xml.

Comment: XML requires a closing tag so it is very inefficient for logging.  And when streamed it is hard to end up with correct XML.  Are yo sure you want (need) this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication189
{   
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Modbus></Modbus>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement modbus = doc.Root;

            modbus.Add(new XElement("Register0", ModbusRTUProtocol.Registers[0]));

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
 
    }
}
```